# Laravel eloquent relationships hasMany two foreign keys error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-7

I use Laravel 7.2 and I've 2 models:

**User**

```
public function orders()
{
    if($this->hasRole("seller")) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'seller_id', 'id');
    } else if($this->hasRole("client")) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Order**

Migration:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
    $table->text('description')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('seller_id');
    $table->foreign('seller_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Code:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}

public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'seller_id');
}
```

Now in my case users has two roles **seller** or **client**. But when I try get user orders laravel return me error message:

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Or when I try get custom order user or seller related data also return same error message.

Where I've any error or I've create relationships incorrectly?

Comment: First, you have an error in your migration file. 
  `$table->id();`
  It would be `$table->bigIncrements('id');`

Comment: From your comment, it is assumed that you are using the old version of the framework. @MuktiRaniGhosh

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice that you are using Laravel 7.2. sorry

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the condition in the relation here:

```
public function orders()
{
    if($this->hasRole("seller")) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'seller_id', 'id');
    } else if($this->hasRole("client")) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Imagine users who has neither roles 'seller' or 'client' then `Null` will be returned and that is exactly the issue.

I recommend you to split the method `orders` into two methods `sellerOrders` and `clientOrders`.

Comment: I was an option in a split format, but I wanted everything to be in one related data. And I have users with the indicated roles in the question, but it turns out that they are not available inside the model’s custom methods. I checked and concluded that related data exp. `roles` in my case is only available when your use eloquent `accessors`.